# PostGIS 3.0 ST_PointFromText parse error - invalid geometry

Tags: postgis, error, postgis-3.0

A customer of ours is using PostGIS on AWS RDS (PostGIS 3.0/PostgreSQL 12.7) and is getting the following error when using ST_PointFromText:

```
ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT: "POINT(25" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
CONTEXT: SQL function "st_pointfromtext" statement 1
SQL state: XX000
```

I cannot see anything wrong with the syntax of the statement being executed:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   schemaname.tablename 
WHERE  ST_Intersects(geometry,ST_PointFromText('POINT(258673 665856)',27700))
```

I have also executed the same statement in PostGIS 2.5/PostgreSQL 11.13 and it works fine. The customer has also confirmed that the following workaround does work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tablename.schemaname 
WHERE  ST_Intersects(geometry,ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(258673,665856),27700))
```

Does anyone have any idea why ST_PointFromText is failing? Is this a bug in PostGIS 3.0?

Comment: The example query string you posted there does not raise any errors on an instance that matches your versions. I suspect this is may be a non-obvious string character issue - I assume the search point coordinates get inserted dynamically? If so it's probably a good idea to try and catch the *exact* character sequence of that (later) WKT string that is getting parsed into the function by the application (or user, if e.g. copy-pasted). Even pasting the same string as numeric literals into `ST_Point` can be biased - after all the numeric literals get pre-formatted as well at paste time.

Comment: They are actually using straight SQL in pgAdmin with the coordinates hard coded, so not sure what's going on then. The work around is working though, so they are happy for the time being.